# WebView not Working Properly

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I made a url to open through webview and everything worked fine for me except some buttons of the webpage it doesn't respond anything

```
public class browse extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView appwebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);

    String profileID= getIntent().getStringExtra("inputtext");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),profileID,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    appwebview=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings= appwebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
    appwebview.loadUrl("https://statsroyale.com/profile/"+profileID);
    appwebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(appwebview.canGoBack())
        appwebview.goBack();
    else
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

the intent passes text of textfield from MainActivity and depending on that text i used to show profile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably you forgot to activate Javascript in the WebView.

Please try this:

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

instead of:

```
webSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
```

A couple of other settings could help:

```
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: thanks i applied all settings now the buttons are working :-)

Comment: finally, someone found how to make this damn WebView work... - Thanks

Comment: Still sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.  WebView is another design disaster by Google!  I think there are some hidden security code in WebView that is not documented and is messing up with its functionality sometimes...  Android is such a pain for developers.

Comment: worked for me , also fixed color rendering issues , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `appwebview` when it finishes loading as sometimes javascript interaction does not work properly.

```
 appwebview.requestFocus();
```

Comment: as sometimes javascript interaction does not work properly.

Comment: thankyou for ur response, i applied all settings as mentioned by @gil.fernades and it worked